# Cannot create a file in iOS (cocoa error 514.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, csv

In my app I've to create a csv file, so I create this method:

```
+ (void)saveFileFromArray:(NSMutableArray *)promoArray {
    NSMutableString *target = [@"Nome,Cognome,E-mail,Data di nascita,Indirizzo,Città,Cap,Telefono\n" mutableCopy];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in promoArray) {
        [target appendFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@\n",dict[@"name"],dict[@"surname"],dict[@"email"],dict[@"birthdate"],dict[@"address"],dict[@"city"],dict[@"zip"],dict[@"phone"]];
    }
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"profiles.csv"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileName];

    BOOL success = [target writeToURL:url atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Errore: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

But when I run the app, for now it saves the .plist file but it doesn't save the .csv file. When I look at the console it tells me: `Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 514.)`. So I searched in the web what means error 514, I found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html), in which I searched for the error and I found `NSFileWriteInvalidFileNameError = 514`, how I can solve this error? In my method what's the problem.
I hope you can help me to solve this issue

SOLVED BY MYSELF:

```
+ (void)saveFileFromArray:(NSMutableArray *)promoArray {
    NSMutableString *target = [@"Nome,Cognome,E-mail,Data di nascita,Indirizzo,Città,Cap,Telefono\n" mutableCopy];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in promoArray) {
        [target appendFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@\n",dict[@"name"],dict[@"surname"],dict[@"email"],dict[@"birthdate"],dict[@"address"],dict[@"city"],dict[@"zip"],dict[@"phone"]];
    }
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"profiles.csv"];

    BOOL success = [target writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Errore: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an expensive way of doing it; why not write each line to the file rather than building the file in memory?

Comment: What happens if you use: `NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];`?

Comment: Please, please, Stackoverflow is not a forum! Post your solution as an *answer*, not as an update to the question! It's perfectly ok to answer your own question.

Comment: Note: Unless the saveFileFromArray modifies the promoArray I'd pass it in as an immutable array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
BOOL success = [target writeToURL:url atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

to

```
BOOL success = [target writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Comment: For everyone else's benefit, would you care to explain the reason for the error in the original code?